# Programmatic equivalent of edit save without making changes?

Tags: 7, users

**Background**
This is a little unorthodox but we have a custom avatar builder based on the [avatar selection module](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatar_selection), where users can build their own avatars. The information about which images are selected to compose the avatar are stored in a blob in imported user but once the profile is saved, the blob is converted into an image and stored with a reference in the file_managed table.

I "migrated" over the user table from the legacy Drupal 7 website to a new Drupal 7 website in order to preserve the blob, but ignored the image reference in the picture field, for reasons I'm not going to get in to here.

As a result, the user now has a default image until either they or an admin clicks to edit their profile, at which point their avatar selection loads on it's own and the user or admin just has to click save, then the default image updates to the correct avatar.

**Question**
My question is: is there a programmatic equivalent to clicking "edit save" for all user profiles?

**What I've Tried**
I added [bulk operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) and modify entity values to a user search view and tried modifying something in the profile, such as editing a custom field. What ended up happening is that not only was the image not updated, but the edit save method will not work to pull up the blob and the blob information disappears.

This seems to be the case with simple edit user role, make active, or any other bulk edits. It seems that you have to actually have the avatar builder open in order for it to rebuild.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends entirely on how your avatar functionality is implemented. If just calling `$entity->save()` on a loaded (unchanged) entity doesn't do it, that probably leaves either a form alter that's doing something slightly unusual, or javascript. If it's the form alter there'll probably be a reasonably simple way to script it, if it's JS it'll be a lot more complicated

Comment: Looks like it uses `hook_form_user_profile_form_alter` and uses jquery and jcarousel.

Comment: You may want to try to create some custom Rules Component (using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module), using a "User" entity as a parameter, AND with a Rules Action to "Save an entity" (of type user), and thereby using the checkbox to ***force immediate save***. Then use the "execute" link in the Rules UI to unit test it. If it works, you could use VBO with a custom action, which actually executes that Rules Component. Worth trying?